# xslt tag in html property

Tags: html, xslt, umbraco

I am using xslt in Umbraco. I want to get an image from the media folder as a background for a div I'm creating.
My problem is I don`t know how to use both HTML and xslt in the same line (if I even need to)
For example:

```
<div style="background-image: url([get image path via xslt]);"></div>
```

Any ideas on how this can be done?
Thank you!
-Elad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <div style="background-image: url({/root/image});"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied against this XML:

```
<root>
    <image>http://example.com/lolcat.gif</image>
</root>
```

Result is:

```
<div style="background-image: url(http://example.com/lolcat.gif);"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about Umbraco but you can try to read if this is what you wanted.

```
<xsl:element name="div">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">background-image: url(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="[get image path via xslt]"/>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">);</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's a bad one. Very verbose solution, exploiting DOE with no reason.

Comment: It's ok. Once I got the idea I slimmed it down myself.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi: This is not the right solution for your question. Do check the sucint `<div style="background-image: url({image path});"/>` from @Flack's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243566/xslt-tag-in-html-property/5245865#5245865)

Comment: You're right. That`s what I ended up figuring out myself. I just needed a push in the right direction.

Comment: This is what i am looking for. Thanks..!!